# How to include your own css files in a rails application using bower?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bower

I am working on a rails app and I would like to include some custom css files inside my rails application. I would like to separate out the css from bootstrap and the css that I wrote. Could I just put the custom css files inside vendor/assets/bower_components folder in my own css folder?

Is there anything else that I need to do for my css files to be picked up?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can achieve bower functionality in a Rails application.

Although having said that, I'm not sure about your wanting to use it on your `custom.css` file. The file itself will work just as well if you keep it in your `app/assets/stylesheets` folder, which will concatenate it to the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

---

[**Bower-Rails**](https://github.com/42dev/bower-rails)

You'll may wish to consider using `bower-rails`, which seems to just give you the ability to use `bower` within your Rails app. This seems to be specifically for helping you keep your dependencies up to date:

> Dependency file is bower.json in Rails root dir or Bowerfile if you
>   use DSL. Check out changelog for the latest changes and releases.

---

[**RailsAssets**](https://rails-assets.org/)

Another amazing piece of functionality we found recently is "RailsAssets"

This works really well (we use it in production), as it keeps your dependent assets completely up to date. You can use it very simply:

```
#Gemfile
source https://rails-assets.org
gem 'rails-assets-BOWER_PACKAGE_NAME'

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require BOWER_PACKAGE_NAME
```

When running `bundle update`, this will then give you the ability to update your assets in line with your app!